# How can i get the whole json object using JSON PATH when my query meets the expected condition

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have a json array like below:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "store": {
        "book": [{
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees"
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. K. Rowlin"
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "store": {
        "book": [{
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Herman Melville"
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh"
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}]
```

i was trying to fetch the whole json object where books author is `J. K. Rowlin`like

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "store": {
        "book": [{
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees"
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. K. Rowlin"
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I am using [Jayway JsonPath Library](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

an i'm trying something like this `$..store.book[?(@.author=='J. R. R. Tolkien')]` in [Json Path Online Validator](http://jsonpath.com/) and always i am getting the inner object Like this.`[
   {
      "category" : "fiction",
      "author" : "J. K. Rowlin"
   }
]`

Is it possible to get the whole object when query fulfills inner condition?

Comment: Use jackson libraries and parse this json to java object from there you can access every values easily.

Comment: I don't know about JayWay, but with com.google.gson.JsonParser and gson (com.google.code.gson) this is a simple task.

Answer (score -2):

The [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) query language is very similar to JSONPath, so you might consider using jq.  To solve your problem, the following filter could be used:

```
.[] | select( .store.book[].author == "J. K. Rowlin")
```

Or slightly more robustly:

```
.[] | select( any(.store.book[]; .author == "J. K. Rowlin") )
```

Assuming your JSON is in a file named input.json, and that you are using a bash-like shell, you could invoke jq like this:

```
  jq '.[] | select(any(.store.book[]; .author == "J. K. Rowlin"))' input.json
```

Of course, the famous author is J.K. Rowling.